# How to attribute different class in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help !

I want to attribute different className for each `<li>` when it becomes current.
The javascript function attribute the className "tab-current" each time and i don't want this.

Example of what i want :

> When the user click on the second tab i would like that the className become 
>   tab-current2.

> When the user click on the third tab i would like that the className become tab-current3

I hope you will understand me, i am a french developper so it's hard to explain this in english.

This is my html code

```
<div class="tabs tabs-style-fillup">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-1"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-2"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-3"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-4"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-5"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-fillup-6"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <section id="section-fillup-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Assurer le conseil et la vente au client des services et produits (circuits, séjours, forfaits, locations proposés par les TO, billetterie, etc...)</li>
                        <li>Gérer les opérations techniques liées à la vente: réservation des prestations touristiques, émissions des billets, éditions des factures.</li>
                        <li>Veiller à assurer une qualité d'accueil au client et donner une image positive de l'entreprise.</li>
                        <li>Concevoir l'assemblage de prestations (transport, hébergement, restauration, animation) en vue de réaliser un forfait simple</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="section-fillup-2">
                    <strong>Qualités :</strong>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bonne élocution</li>
                        <li>Sens commercial</li>
                        <li>Dynamisme</li>
                        <li>Souriant et accueillant</li>
                    </ul>
                    <strong>Compétences :</strong>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Connaissance des destinations et de l'industrie du tourisme</li>
                        <li>Maitrise des outils professionnels (GDS...)</li>
                        <li>Maîtrise de l'anglais</li>
                        <li>Aptitude à la vente</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="section-fillup-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Le recrutement se fait essentiellement à partir d'un BTS Tourisme</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="section-fillup-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li>A partir du SMIC pour un débutant. En moyenne : 24K€/an.</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="section-fillup-5">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Les agents de voyages, Travel Planners, responsables billetterie évoluent vers des postes de responsable des ventes, responsable clientèle, responsable  d’agence puis de direction</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="section-fillup-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Les agents de voyages, Travel Planners, responsables billetterie évoluent vers des postes de responsable des ventes, responsable clientèle, responsable  d’agence puis de direction</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
            </div>
            <script src="http://www.efht.fr/beta/wp-content/themes/mirror-wp/tab/cbpFWTabs.js"></script>
                <script>
                    (function() {

                    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
                            new CBPFWTabs( el );
                        });

                    })();
                </script>
```

Here is my JavaScript :

```
;( function( window ) {

                'use strict';

                function extend( a, b ) {
                    for( var key in b ) { 
                        if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                            a[key] = b[key];
                        }
                    }
                    return a;
                }

                function CBPFWTabs( el, options ) {
                    this.el = el;
                    this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
                    extend( this.options, options );
                    this._init();
                }

                CBPFWTabs.prototype.options = {
                    start : 0
                };

                CBPFWTabs.prototype._init = function() {
                    // tabs elems
                    this.tabs = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'nav > ul > li' ) );
                    // content items
                    this.items = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.content-wrap > section' ) );
                    // current index
                    this.current = -1;
                    // show current content item
                    this._show();
                    // init events
                    this._initEvents();
                };

                CBPFWTabs.prototype._initEvents = function() {
                    var self = this;
                    this.tabs.forEach( function( tab, idx ) {
                        tab.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                            ev.preventDefault();
                            self._show( idx );
                        } );
                    } );
                };

                CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function( idx ) {
                    if( this.current >= 0 ) {
                        this.tabs[ this.current ].className = this.items[ this.current ].className = '';
                    }
                    // change current
                    this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0;
                    this.tabs[ this.current ].className = 'tab-current';
                    this.items[ this.current ].className = 'content-current';
                };

                // add to global namespace
                window.CBPFWTabs = CBPFWTabs;

            })( window );
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this by modifying the `_show()` function to append the index of the element to the class name:

```
CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function( idx ) {
    if( this.current >= 0 ) {
        this.tabs[ this.current ].className = this.items[ this.current ].className = '';
    }
    // change current
    this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0;
    this.tabs[ this.current ].className = 'tab-current' + (idx + 1); // <--- HERE
    this.items[ this.current ].className = 'content-current';
};
```

Since the indices start at `0`, to get the "first" tab to show `1`, you must add `1` to `idx`.